# Visualise missing values in a time series heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap, missing-data

I am really new in big data analysing.
Let's say I have a big data with the following features. I want to visualise the the percentage of missing values (None values) of fuel parameters for every id in specific hour. I want to draw a chart that x-axis is the time series (time column), y-axis is the 'id' and the colour will indicate its missing fuel percentage.
I grouped the data base on 'id' and 'hour'

I don't know how to visualise missing value in a good way for all ids. For example if the percentage of missing value fuel of specific id in specific hour is 100% then the colour in that specific time and for that 'id' can be gray. If percentage of missing value in fuel is 50%, the colour can be light green. If percentage of missing value in fuel is 0% then the colour can be dark green.
The colour must be based to the percentage of missing value in fuel, after grouping based on id and time.

```
    id    time                   fuel
0   1     2022-02-26 19:08:33    100
2   1     2022-02-26 20:09:35    None
3   2     2022-02-26 21:09:35    70
4   3     2022-02-26 21:10:55    60
5   4     2022-02-26 21:10:55    None
6   5     2022-02-26 22:12:43    50
7   6     2022-02-26 23:10:50    None
```

So for example, in the following code I computed the percentage of the missing value for every hour for specific id:

```
df.set_index('ts').groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(freq='H')])['fuell'].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().mean() * 100)
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: See this module for missing data visualization: https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno

Comment: I saw this but didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The heatmap now plots `id` vs `time` vs percentage of null `fuel`. I've kept my original answer for `id` vs `time` vs `fuel` at the end of this post.

---

> I want something almost like a github style calendar.

To mimic the GitHub contribution matrix, reset the grouped null percentages into a dataframe and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) into 1 `id` per row and 1 hour per column. Then use [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to color each cell based on percentage of null `fuel`.

```
# convert to proper dtypes
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['fuel'] = pd.to_numeric(df['fuel'], errors='coerce')

# compute null percentage per (id, hour)
nulls = (df.set_index('time')
           .groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(freq='H')])['fuel']
           .apply(lambda x: x.isnull().mean() * 100))

# pivot into id vs time matrix
matrix = (nulls.reset_index(name='null (%)')
               .pivot(index='id', columns='time', values='null (%)'))

# plot time series heatmap
sns.heatmap(matrix, square=True, vmin=0, vmax=100, cmap='magma_r', cbar_kws={'label': 'null (%)'},
            linewidth=1, linecolor='lightgray', clip_on=False,
            xticklabels=matrix.columns.strftime('%b %d, %Y\n%H:%M:%S'))
```

[image]

---

**Original:** This is for visualizing `id` by `time` by `fuel`:

1. Pivot into an `id` vs `time` matrix. Normally [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) is fine, but since your real data contains duplicate indexes, use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).
2. [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) the `time` columns into hourly means.
3. Plot the time series matrix using [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).

```
# convert to proper dtypes
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['fuel'] = pd.to_numeric(df['fuel'], errors='coerce')

# pivot into id vs time matrix
matrix = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='time', values='fuel', dropna=False)

# resample columns into hourly means
matrix = matrix.resample('H', axis=1).mean()

# plot time series heatmap
sns.heatmap(matrix, square=True, cmap='plasma_r', vmin=0, vmax=100, cbar_kws={'label': 'fuel (%)'},
            linewidth=1, linecolor='lightgray', clip_on=False,
            xticklabels=matrix.columns.strftime('%b %d, %Y\n%H:%M:%S'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However still there is a problem. In the dataset sometimes we have same 'id' with different timestamp and fuel. in this situation I encounter this error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape . And As you see in my question I grouped the data by id and time.

Comment: In that case you change `pivot` to `pivot_table` with `dropna=False` (code updated).

Comment: Great! Can you also please add my part of code to your code. Because I want to compute the percentage of missing value after grouping by 'id' and 'hour'.

Comment: How do your computed percentages relate to the heatmap? Do you mean you want the cell color to be based on those computed percentages, rather than the raw `fuel` values?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want the cell color be based on the computed percentages.

Comment: Ok, see if the updated version is what you're looking for. Note that the new version should work with just `pivot`, but you can change it to `pivot_table` if you get a duplicate index error again (`pivot_table` is slower, so generally it's better to avoid it unless necessary).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Regarding the second graph, right now if the fuel is null or zero, in both cases it shows yellow color. How can distinguish between both(zero and null) and show it in the graph?

Comment: @user2064809 I had added `fillna(0)` to `matrix`, which actually doesn't make sense now that I think about it. If anything, `fillna(100)` would make more sense, but you can also just remove the `fillna` entirely (code/output updated).

Comment: Right now if for example we have (None,None,0,None,None), it gives us 0 as output. but in this case the output must be None. How can I fix this problem.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding something. I added some rows to group 6 to make it (None,None,0,None,None), and the code return 80% null for group 6. Are you saying it should be 100% null, as in 0 should just always be interpreted as None? Or if you're talking about a different scenario, can you provide a data sample?

Comment: I am talking about the graph that shows fuel%. For example for the following dataset. We have id=1, it shows yellow. Yellow means zero. 
But the fuel is [None,None,0,None,None]. How can we distinguish between None and zero in the graph?
data = {
 'id':['1','1','1','1','1'],
        'time':[
                '2022-02-26 22:12:30','2022-02-26 22:22:40', '2022-02-26 22:22:50',
                '2022-02-26 22:22:56','2022-02-26 22:56:43'],
       'fuel':[None,None,0,None,None]}

Comment: Since those 5 timestamps are all within one hour, they get aggregated into a single value (the mean for that hour). The result is 0 due to an old bug where pandas always ignores NaN in groupby/resample operations ([#15675](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15675), [#29382](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29382)). `skipna=False` is also not supported for groupby/resample methods. If you want to include NaNs, this is the only way I could get it to work (double transpose with custom lambda): `matrix.T.resample('H').agg(lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False)).T`

Comment: Now if we have something like this:[0,None,0,0,0], it assumes is None and ignore all zeros. I mean it would be great if it find the frequency and show the things that has more frequency. for example in this example it must show 0. If it is [None,None,0,None,None], it must show None. But anyway thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer concerning missing values visualization, I guess it depends on your uses, habits ...

But first, to make it works, we need to preprocess your dataframe and make it analyzable, aka ensure its dtypes.

First let's build our data :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
    
csvfile = StringIO(
"""id   time    fuel
1   2022-02-26 19:08:33 100
2   2022-02-26 19:09:35 70
3   2022-02-26 19:10:55 60
4   2022-02-26 20:10:55 None
5   2022-02-26 21:12:43 50
6   2022-02-26 22:10:50 None""")
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

df
Out[65]: 
   id                 time  fuel
0   1  2022-02-26 19:08:33   100
1   2  2022-02-26 19:09:35    70
2   3  2022-02-26 19:10:55    60
3   4  2022-02-26 20:10:55  None
4   5  2022-02-26 21:12:43    50
5   6  2022-02-26 22:10:50  None
```

At this stage almost all data in our dataframe is string related, you need to convert fuel and time into a non-object dtypes.

```py
df.dtypes
Out[66]: 
id       int64
time    object
fuel    object
dtype: object
```

Time should be converted as datetime, id as int and fuel as float. Indeed, None should be convert as np.nan for numeric values, which needs the float dtype.

With a map, we can easily change all `'None'` values into `np.nan`. I won't go deeper here, but for simplicity sake, I'll use a custom subclass of dict with a [`__missing__`](https://blog.finxter.com/python-__missing__-magic-method/) implementation

```py
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

class dict_with_missing(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key
map_dict = dict_with_missing({'None' : np.nan})
df.fuel = df.fuel.map(map_dict).astype(np.float32)
```

Then we have a clean dataframe :

```py
df
Out[68]: 
   id                time   fuel
0   1 2022-02-26 19:08:33  100.0
1   2 2022-02-26 19:09:35   70.0
2   3 2022-02-26 19:10:55   60.0
3   4 2022-02-26 20:10:55    NaN
4   5 2022-02-26 21:12:43   50.0
5   6 2022-02-26 22:10:50    NaN

df.dtypes
Out[69]: 
id               int64
time    datetime64[ns]
fuel           float32
dtype: object
```

Then, you can easily use `bar`, `matrix` or `heatmap` from the [`missingno`](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/data-science/missingno-visualize-missing-data-in-python#ref) module

```py
msno.bar(df)
msno.matrix(df, sparkline=False)
msno.heatmap(df, cmap="RdYlGn")
```

A side note here, heatmap is kind of useless here, since it compares columns having missing values. And you only have one column with missing value. But for a bigger dataframe (~ 5/6 columns with missing values) it can be useful.

For a quick and dirty visualization, you can also print the number of missing value (aka np.nan, in pandas/numpy formulation) :

```py
df.isna().sum()
Out[72]: 
id      0
time    0
fuel    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Doesn't shows for me the time series in x-axis

Comment: For a heatmap, it's not how it works. Heatmap for missing value looks for correlation between different columns. If it's not what you are looking for, edit your question to be more accurate, such as a desired output. Nonetheless, missingno is kind of standard in missing data visualization. Furthermore, timeseries are a time-related array, are you talking about your time column ?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about time column.
I want something almost like ‘github style calendar’. Which x-axis be the time and y-axis be the the ‘id’. I edit the question. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Still not 100% clear, do you want some % of missing value for a said time interval or cumulative ? If time is your index (better use), you can use `df.fuel.expanding().apply(lambda x : x.isna().sum() / len(x))` to compute the cumulative percentage of np.nan depending of time : 

`time
2022-02-26 19:08:33    0.000000
2022-02-26 19:09:35    0.000000
2022-02-26 19:10:55    0.000000
2022-02-26 20:10:55    0.250000
2022-02-26 21:12:43    0.200000
2022-02-26 22:10:50    0.333333`